# Set string = to function in r

Tags: r, function

I'm interested in why you would set `"string" <- function(x)`. I am interested in some feedback on what this does. I have included some code below. The function is within a larger function. I understand what `unique()`, `which.max()`, `tabulate()`, and `match()` are doing, but I am confused on `"mode" <- function(x)`

The code was sent to me from another party, and works fine. I'm just interested in what it does.

```
metric = function(z, i, rn, minht, above)
{
    "mode" <- function(x){
        ux <-unique(x)
        ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x,ux)))]
}
    metrics = list(
    )
    return(metrics)
}
```

Comment: I think it does the same thing it would without the quotes around the word mode. `?'<-'` says `x` (the LHS) should be "a variable name (possibly quoted)."

Comment: Given the context by @IceCreamToucan, I can see no benefit to defining a function in this way: (1) it is functionally identical to `mode <- function(x){...`; (2) it is no faster; (3) code-highlighting looks different, so depending on the IDE being used, it may look differently than a function definition normally would ... might be good/bad depending on your IDE.

Comment: I agree it is functionally identical and does the same thing without quotes. Thanks for helping clear things up!